# Bootstrap 4 Image Card Flip On Click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot figure out how to make it so that, on click, an image will flip around and information can be read on the back side of the card. Every codepen example I have tried adding simply will not work. Heres my card as is:

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" class="card-img" alt="...">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a deck of the above cards, and would like each to flip when clicked. I already have various custom CSS applied to the .card class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted this CSS on w3schools to work with your HTML. I did have to add a div with the class `card-inner`, because otherwise the hovering is a bit buggy.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card

```css
.card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card:hover .card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card img, .card-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;
}

.card-img-overlay {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="card-inner">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" class="card-img" alt="...">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ON CLICK**

```js
// Get card element
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

// Loop through cards. 
// This is so you can have multiple cards on a page.
for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
   // Add a click event listener to each card.
   card[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     // Toggle active class on card
     card[i].classList.toggle("active");
   });
}
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card.active .card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card img, .card-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;
}

.card-img-overlay {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="card-inner">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" class="card-img" alt="...">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you- how would I make this work on click? Thanks.

Comment: @S.Stevens You would have to use javascript to toggle a class on click. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you, I have nearly got it working now. One thing, however, is that as the card flips the border appears to be black and there is a background of grey (as it flips). Not quite sure why.

Comment: Not sure. I'm not seeing that in chrome. Might be browser related.

Comment: I am also in chrome...Where abouts in the CSS does it set the background colour as it flips?

Comment: Nevermind, I appear to have figured this out. I am just trying to figure out how to enable a different set of CSS for different cards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .scene {
      width: 200px;
      height: 260px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      margin: 40px 0;
      perspective: 600px;
    }
    
    .card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transition: transform 1s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .card.is-flipped {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    .card__face {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      line-height: 260px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 40px;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .card__face--front {
      background: red;
    }
    
    .card__face--back {
      background: blue;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scene scene--card">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
      <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Click card to flip.</p>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var card = document.querySelector('.card');
    card.addEventListener('click', function() {
      card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```